# no puedo hacer una inserción de datos en mysql mediante php

Tags: php, html, mysql

me aparecen estos errores al ejecutar este php, alguien que me ayude a solucionarlo porfavor

Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica2\insertar.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica2\insertar.php on line 13
Error

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include "conexion.php";
    if (isset($_POST['Insert'])) {      
            $clasificacion = $_POST['clasificacion'];
            $titulo        = $_POST['titulo'];
            $autor         = $_POST['autor'];
            $anio          = $_POST['anio'];
            $editorial     = $_POST['editorial'];
            $isbn          = $_POST['isbn'];
            $result = 0;

                $sql = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO libro(clasificacion, titulo, autor, año, editorial, isbn) VALUES ('$clasificacion', '$titulo', '$autor', '$anio', '$editorial', '$isbn');");

                if($sql){

                    ;
                echo("guardado");
                }else{

                exit( "Error" );    
                }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Deberías escribir el código que tienes para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Vika, por favor, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Al parecer la conexión no está funcionando y está retornando el null, deberías revisar esa parte de tu código porque la conexión a tu base de datos no se está realizando

Comment: puedes poner tu fichero conexion.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa tu fichero conexión debe tener el siguiente formato:

```
  <?php
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "tu usuario";
    $password = "tu pass";
    $dbname = "tu db";
    
    // Creamos la conexion y seleccionamos la base de datos
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conexion) {
        die("Conexion fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
            
    ?>
```

Después para realizar la inserción en tu base de datos realízala de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
    
    include "conexion.php";
    if (isset($_POST['Insert'])) {      
            $clasificacion = $_POST['clasificacion'];
            $titulo        = $_POST['titulo'];
            $autor         = $_POST['autor'];
            $anio          = $_POST['anio'];
            $editorial     = $_POST['editorial'];
            $isbn          = $_POST['isbn'];
           

$query = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO libro(clasificacion, titulo, autor, año, editorial, isbn) VALUES ('$clasificacion', '$titulo', '$autor', '$anio', '$editorial', '$isbn');");
      
if (!$query) {
        die("Fallo en la insercion de registro en la Base de Datos: " . mysqli_error());
    }

mysqli_close($conexion);
echo ("GRABADOS");
```

De este modo no tiene por que darte ningún problema

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió